# Moving file to another folder after performing search and replace operation on it

Tags: regex, linux, shell

Please help me out here:

I'm using the below command to search and replace strings in files in a directory (including sub-directories):

```
find . -type f -exec perl -api -e 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/dummy/g' {} \;
```

What I want to is after it performs the above operation on a file, I want to simultaneously move it to another folder and then work on the next file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -api -e 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/dummy/g' {} \; -exec mv {} /to/this/directory \;
```

After the first `-exec` predicate completes successfully, `find` will run the next `-exec`. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55652/162065) answer to a related question will give you a bit more information.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to is after it performs the above operation on a file, I want to simultaneously move it to another folder and then work on the next file.

You can do:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   perl -ap -e 's/\b(?!00)[A-Z0-9]{6,}/dummy/g' "$file" > "/dest/$file"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

This will also take care of files with white-spaces and special characters.